# How can I get each jObject from json.net?

Tags: json.net, latitude-longitude

I need to get first and last latitude and longitude from mapquestapi, passing street address. First of all, passing lat and long I can get house_number, using json.net:

```
string latitu = "-33.4479021";
string longitu = "-70.6447504";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&lat=" + latitu + "&lon=" + longitu + "");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

string houseNumber = (string)jObject["address"]["house_number"];

Console.WriteLine(houseNumber);
stream.Close();
```

The code below works fine, but now I need to get the first and last lat and long from "svg":

```
array ( 
0 => array 
    ( 'place_id' => '92911594', 
    'licence' => 
    'Data Â© OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright', 
    'osm_type' => 'way', 
    'osm_id' => '121748552', 
    'boundingbox' => array 
        ( 
            0 => '-33.4480414', 
            1 => '-33.4439319', 
            2 => '-70.6448054', 
            3 => '-70.6266944', 
        ), 
    'lat' => '-33.4460658', 
    'lon' => '-70.6359402', 
    'display_name' => 'MarÃ­n, Santiago, Provincia de Santiago, XIII RegiÃ³n Metropolitana de Santiago, 8331059, Chile', 
    'class' => 'highway', 
    'type' => 'tertiary', 
    'importance' => 0.2, 
    'address' => array 
    ( 
        'road' => 
        'MarÃ­n', 
        'city' => 
        'Santiago', 
        'county' => 
        'Provincia de Santiago', 
        'state' => 'XIII RegiÃ³n Metropolitana de Santiago', 
        'postcode' => '8331059', 
        'country' => 'Chile', 
        'country_code' => 'cl', 
    ), 
    **'svg'** => 'M **-70.626694400000005 33.444016900000001** L -70.626853100000005 33.443931900000003 -70.628024600000003 33.444266200000001 -70.629083399999999 33.444542800000001 -70.629957200000007 33.444764300000003 -70.630791099999996 33.444983999999998 -70.630836099999996 33.4449915 -70.631027500000002 33.445031299999997 -70.631102900000002 33.445044099999997 -70.631955300000001 33.445186900000003 -70.632777300000001 33.445343999999999 -70.632846900000004 33.445356799999999 -70.6329025 33.445371799999997 -70.633783199999996 33.445576199999998 -70.634021200000007 33.445624299999999 -70.635066499999994 33.4458354 -70.635940199999993 33.4460658 -70.637316900000002 33.446388900000002 -70.638039300000003 33.446610700000001 -70.638551500000005 33.446730799999997 -70.639778699999994 33.447019400000002 -70.640489099999996 33.4471962 -70.641005800000002 33.4473074 -70.642197100000004 33.447521299999998 -70.642251900000005 33.447535500000001 -70.643692900000005 33.4478121 **-70.644805399999996 33.448041400000001**', 
    ), )
```

I'm tryng this but an error says that its not an object:

```
string direcc = "marin,+santiago";
          //string url = "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?&q="+direcc+"&format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1&countrycodes=cl";
          WebClient client = new WebClient();
          Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?&q=" + direcc + "&format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1&countrycodes=cl");
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

          Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

          string la = (string)jObject["address"]["svg"];

          Console.WriteLine(la);
          stream.Close();
```

This work, but i dont know how to get the first and last lat and long:

```
string latitud = "-33.4479021";
string longitud = "-70.6447504";
string url = "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&lat=" + latitud +"&lon=" + longitud + "";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
          string xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
          Console.WriteLine(xmlText);
```

What can i do for get this part? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me...  But I guess the value of the `svg` property is a string and not another JSON object. Therefore you're going to have to parse the string yourself. This will be easier if you can find a definition of what the string contains (rather than guessing from samples).

Comment: Thanks! look, this work but I dont know how to parse first and last lat and lon: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
          string xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
          Console.WriteLine(xmlText);

Comment: You need to start by understanding the string you need to parse: try reading the documentation for the API.